# How to run two XMPP clients and exchange messages on the same machine

Tags: server, software-installation, empathy

I'm new to XMPP stuff and try to get my hands dirty. This is what I've done by now:

1. Installed ejabberd
2. Created two accounts `user1@localhost` and `user2@localhost`
3. Installed Psi plus client
4. Installed Empathy client

Now I want to open `Psi plus` under `user1` and `Empathy` - under `user2`. It seems like there is no problem with `Psi plus` - I logged in under `user1` and can send messages to myself and hear notifications. But I can not do the same thing with `Empathy`. When I do

```
$ empathy
```

I see a window with `Contact list` title and one combobox with values like `Available`, `Custom message...` etc. I do not see any tool where I could specify or choose `user2` account and I do not see any window that I could use to send messages. So, I need some instructions.

Answer (score 1):

- Start `empathy` and you will see the <kbd>Contact List</kbd>

  [image]
- Click <kbd>Account Settings</kbd> or select <kbd>Accounts</kbd> in the menu

  [image]
- Use the <kbd>+</kbd> to add accounts, select <kbd>Jabber</kbd> for XMPP

  [image]

Comment: Thanks! And how can I add new contacts (like `user1` which uses `Psi plus` client in my example)?

Comment: You can't create new accounts. You can only use existing accounts.

Comment: I'm asking not about account now, but about a new contact, so that I could send a message from `user2` who uses `Empathy` to `user1` who uses `Psi plus`

Comment: For example, in `Empathy` for some strange reason `Add contact...` button is disabled. So that when I run it under `user2`, I can not add `user1` to my contact list.

Comment: I added contact user2@localhost in `psi plus`. However, when I send messages to `user2`, I see nothing happening on part of `Empathy` window, opened by `user2` - no notifications etc. Besides in message window `user2` is for some reason marked as `offline`. So, I still can not make it all work.

Comment: `https://help.gnome.org/users/empathy/stable/add-contact.html.ru` says `1. Choose Chat ▸ Add Contact.` , but I can not see anywhere these options `Choose Chat` or `Add Contact` in `Empathy`. `Add contact..` button is disabled, the only combobox under `Contact List` title has some other options. The menu button on the toolbar has these options: `Open hidden in background`, `Open preferences`, `Open accounts`, `Empathy Internet messaging`, `Lock to launcher` and `Quit` - so, nothing similar to `Choose chat` or `Add contact`.